# how to response before the server return on iOS

Tags: ios

my situation is  like this:

when you press a button, it will first hide the button, and then send a http request to the server, the request is sent to a php script and execute an "exe" to use the printer to print something.

But when I test the app, I find the button hides when the "exe" on the server exits, the result is that when I press the button, the application is like "not response", the button 
dose not hide and keep the state of "press down", it is not user-friendly. So any ideas
to help me solve this ?

---

Finally, I used slef performSelectorInBackground, since I did not care the result php return, it works well and easier than Asynchronous call.

Comment: It's better to post your solution as an answer rather than editing your question; note that you can even select your own answer as the accepted one, so this question can be closed...

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are making a synchronous call to the server. Check here for how to make asynchronous calls.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

interface updates are only done after the method finishes. try running the php part in an extra method with performSelector:

```
- (void)yourCurrentMethod {
    button.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething)];
}

- (void)doSomething {
    /* call php script, etc */
}
```

Comment: -performSelector is asynchronous? What is difference between [self doSomething] and [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething)] ? the former is synchronous and the latter is asynchronous ?

Comment: I would suggest [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething)] if you want to let it run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what I meant was performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

```
- (void)yourCurrentMethod {
    button.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)doSomething {
    /* call php script, etc */
}
```

That will process the hidden in the UI and then call the doSomething-method without making it a background thread, so you can use a synchronous request. Using asynchronous requests is a little more work (but cleaner), which you don't really need, if you only want to call the php and don't care about the result.

Comment: I finally use [performSelectorInBackground], it works well, thank you